# PERC H710 says “Update key missing”

Tags: dell, hardware-raid, dell-perc

I currently scavenged a thrift shop in japan and picked up a working mint condition poweredge T110 II. It’s already been powered up and have ESXi on it. I recently bought a PERC H710 by LSI to upgrade the drives and as soon as i power it up now it displays “Upgrade Key Missing! An upgrade key was present on a previous power cycle, but it is not connected. This can result in inaccessible data unless it is addressed. Please reattach the upgrade key and reboot.”
Im not able to go into boot or do any type of update, any help would be appreciated as I’ve ran out of ideas. There was an old post here saying he unplugged it and plugged it back in, but that’s not working for me.